# What's the diffence between these 2 javascript methods with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading a tutorial related to High Order Components in React and I found this:

```
save = () => {
   // some logic
}
```

What is the difference, if there is one, between the way above with the one I was familiar with:

```
methodName () {
   // some logic
}
```

Comment: The difference is that the first named `save` and the second is `methodName`. Nothing in common! But if serious, read about class properties and arrow functions. The key here is context.

Comment: Good one! haha
Thanks, but do I need something special to use the first one? I'm getting a syntax error. I'm using babel with the last preset and react as well.